# ReentrantLock : Can multiple threads acquire write lock simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a method fetchAndMoveMessageInfo which will be accessed by multiple thread concurrently which does following thing:

1. if global queue cache empty : fills the queue cache (ConcurrentLinkedQueue) by performing the read ops But make sure only one thread perform this item other should wait
2. if cache is not empty then just pop one Item thread safely. I mean no two thread pop the same item.

For 2nd requirement I used ConcurrentLinkedQueue to assure that no thread  pop the same item.

For the 1st requirement I have used ReentrantLock Lock so that the thread which acquire the write lock should perform the db read ops to fill the cahce other reader should wait for cache to be filled. Once cache is filled then read threads the queue cahce concurrently.

I have following query:

1. Is my above design OK ? But I observe that when the messageinfo count decreases in the db this throughput goes down sharply as the number of  messageinfos goes down. I think this is because the contention and more number of db reads when messsgeInofs are less. for example if writer fetchs 600 messageInfos then all other thread will get rest of 599 from cache. But if there are only 2 messages fetched by writer(the one who acquires the write lock and read from db) as the number of messages are less. and this will cause contention and more number of db queries . is my doubt correct? Do i have to live with this or is there any better approach we have to deal with this problem ?
2. I also observe contention for a method which is synchronized and only get invoked getDequeueMessageInfo . I am clueless here how come this method gets contention when ReentrantLock lock assues that at a time thre will be only writer.
3. Is there any better design? Please give suggestion.

Below is snapshot of my code and JFR contention snapshot.

```
      //the queue is ConcurrentLinkedQueue
      static Map<String, Queue<MsgInfo>> queueReadBucketNextMessageIds = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Queue<MsgInfo>>();
  private final Map<String,ReentrantReadWriteLock > readWriteLockMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();    
     //Applying read write ReentrantLock Lock to improve performance as number of db read op decreases when the cache  will have around 500 messgeInfos
        public MsgInfo fetchAndMoveMessageInfo(String queueName,
                Date dequeuetime, Date dequeueMinute) {
            getReadWriteLock(queueName).readLock().lock(); //acquire read lock
            if (!hasMessageInfo(queueName)) {
                getReadWriteLock(queueName).readLock().unlock(); //unlock read lock
                getReadWriteLock(queueName).writeLock().lock(); //acquire write lock
                // Acquired writeLock
                try {
                    if (!hasMessageInfo(queueName)) {
                        return getDequeueMessageInfo(queueName, dequeuetime,
                                dequeueMinute); //Form this I am invoking a method getReadBucketForQueue which is showing contention. See below JFR contention. How ??
                    }
                    getReadWriteLock(queueName).readLock().lock(); //unlock write lock

                } finally {
                    getReadWriteLock(queueName).writeLock().unlock(); //unlock read lock
                }

            }
            try {
                return readAndHideMessageInfo(queueName, dequeuetime, dequeueMinute);
            } finally {
                getReadWriteLock(queueName).readLock().unlock();
            }
        }

         private boolean hasMessageInfo(String queueName) {
            boolean hasMessageInfo = false;
            if (queueReadBucketNextMessageIds.containsKey(queueName)) {
                Queue<MsgInfo> messageInfoQueue = queueReadBucketNextMessageIds
                        .get(queueName);
                synchronized (messageInfoQueue) {
                    hasMessageInfo = !messageInfoQueue.isEmpty();
                }
            }
        private MsgInfo readAndHideMessageInfo(String queueName, Date dequeuetime,
                Date dequeueMinute) {
            MsgInfo messageInfo = queueReadBucketNextMessageIds.get(queueName)
                    .poll();
            if (messageInfo != null)
                //perform a db operation here to move 
            return messageInfo;
        }

private ReentrantReadWriteLock getReadWriteLock(String queueName) {
        ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = readWriteLockMap.get(queueName);
        if (readWriteLock == null) {
            log.debug("getting readWriteLock for newly created queue {}",
                    queueName);
            ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
            readWriteLock = readWriteLockMap.putIfAbsent(queueName, lock);
            if (readWriteLock == null)
                readWriteLock = lock;
        }
        return readWriteLock;
    }       
    Stack Trace  of JFR contention                                                                            Count Duration
    com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceHelper.setReadBucketForQueue(String, List)                5,134  8 min 39 sec
       com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceHelper.getDequeueMessageInfo(String, Date, Date)       5,125  8 min 39 sec
          com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceHelper.fetchAndMoveMessageInfo(String, Date, Date)  5,125  8 min 39 sec
             com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceImpl.dequeue(String)                             5,125  8 min 39 sec

       com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceHelper.getReadBucketForQueue(String)                       9  1 sec 245 ms (How come this method is showing contention?clueless ?)
          com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceHelper.getDequeueMessageInfo(String, Date, Date)        9  1 sec 245 ms
             com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceHelper.fetchAndMoveMessageInfo(String, Date, Date)   9  1 sec 245 ms
                com.owmessaging.qserv.service.impl.QueueServiceImpl.dequeue(String) 9   1,245,024,161
```

Comment: Can multiple threads acquire the same lock at the same time?  No.  That would defeat the purpose of locking.  Usually when somebody thinks a `synchronized(foo)` block or a `ReentrantLock foo;` isn't working, it turns out to be that their `foo` variable does not always refer to the same object.

Comment: Hard to tell with your code example, though:  It's sketchy---missing pieces.  You'd be more likely to get a good answer if you'd post code that other people can actually compile and run, explain how you _expected_ it to behave, and let them see for themselves how it actually _does_ behave.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James. I completely understand your concern regarding my code snapshot. It is little difficult for now me to put a simple version of that. However i am debugging myself keeping your point in mind that  "foo variable does not always refer to the same object" . Although i have tried my best that the ReentrantLock  object should be unique per queue for that i kept a map and which i am filling at startup of application But incase if queue is new than my getReadWriteLock method handles it as well (I have attached my implementation).

Comment: You don't have to post a simple version of your program, you only have to post a simple program that does something you don't understand.  That is, you iterate, simplifying the parts that you _do_ understand, and trying to isolate the bad behavior.  Either you end up figuring it out for yourself (usually the most rewarding outcome), or you end up with something small that you can post here.  See http://sscce.org/ for a more complete description of the process.